# jQuery conditional loading in template

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to load my template conditionally in Jquery. what i have right now :

```
<script type="text/html"​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ id="template">
    <div id ="myID" style="background-color: #009ACF">
        <span questionLabelGroup="$i">Question :</span>
        <span questionTextGroup="$i">$textboxText<br /></span>
        <span answerLabelGroup="$i">Answer : </span>
        <input  type='text' questionID="$guid"/>
        {{if buildLinkb("id") == null }}
        <input type='button' Class='addAnswerButton' addQuestionButtonGroup='"$i"' value='Add Question' />
        <hr />
    </div>
        {{/if}}
</script>
```

where buildLinkb("id") is :

```
function buildLinkb(param) {
    var val = document.URL;
    var url = val.substr(val.indexOf(param))  
    var n=parseInt(url.replace(param+"=",""));
    alert(n+1); 
}
```

So what happends is, on document ready i am loading this template from ajax call to server. In url send id parameter conditionally, and i want to load parts of a template if id does not exsists.

Any way of diong it?

Comment: Please explain further what you want?

Comment: problem is that {{if buildLinkb("id") == null }} doesnt work, so i need to find a way to add this condition into template

Answer (score 0):

In the document.ready event

Send an initial ajax request. If found then you can append the elements to your div.. Otherwise do nothing..

You can achieve this in you success callback function